# how to create production build in NextJS app

Tags: next.js

The following error is occured when run cmd "next build".

[image]

Comment: Why not try executing it with npx

Comment: How? Can you please tell me the cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Add a build script in your `package.json`, so that you can run `npm run build` or `yarn build`. Just make sure `next` is installed as one of the dependencies.

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build"
  },
```

Alternatively, you may run `npx next build`.